# scala play twitter api oauth authentication doesnt work

Tags: scala, twitter, oauth, playframework

using play 2.4 to access twitter api with oauth. 
I created an app on twitter and created key and token with secrets. 
on twitter made up a URL for my application as it actually doesnt exist. 
and used the same made up url on callback url. Runing the application on localhost.Using curl generated command from twitter to mimic authentication works as expected so my keys and tokens are valid.

I get this response when I run my code :

Error 401 Unauthorized

This is main play code :

```scala
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.libs.oauth.{ConsumerKey,RequestToken}
import scala.concurrent.Future
import play.api.libs.ws._
import play.api.libs.oauth.OAuthCalculator
import play.api.libs.iteratee._

class Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }

  val loggingIteratee = Iteratee.foreach[Array[Byte]] { array => Logger.info(array.map(_.toChar).mkString) }

  def tweets = Action.async {
    credentials.map {
      case (consumerKey, requestToken) =>
        println(consumerKey.key.toString())
        println(consumerKey.secret.toString())
        println(requestToken.token.toString())
        println(requestToken.secret.toString())
        WS
          .url("https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json")
          .sign(OAuthCalculator(consumerKey, requestToken))
          .withQueryString("track" -> "reactive")
          .get()
          .map { response =>
            Ok(response.body)
          }
    }getOrElse{
      Future{
        InternalServerError("twitter credentials missing")
      }
    }
  }

  def credentials :Option[(ConsumerKey,RequestToken)] = for {
      apiKey <- Play.configuration.getString("twitter.apiKey")
      apiSecret <- Play.configuration.getString("twitter.apiSecret")
      token <- Play.configuration.getString("twitter.token")
      tokenSecret <- Play.configuration.getString("twitter.tokenSecret")
  }yield (ConsumerKey(apiKey,apiSecret),RequestToken(token,tokenSecret) )

}
```

Comment: Play 2.4 oauth is broken.

Comment: @bwawok is there a bug for it ? as in is it a known issue ?

Comment: I think so, working troubleshooting over at https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/4826   . So far looks like something is wrong with async http that got upgrades with play 2.4. I bet your code works in play 2.3.

Comment: I dont think Play 2.4 oauth is broken as I just got it working for me. See my below post. Thanks for your input anyway..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you use the false Twitter API. As mentioned [here](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/get/statuses/sample) you have to use the Twitter API 1.1 so the URL for your webservice should be: `.url("https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json")`

Comment: As you used cURL was is twurl from twitter or the normal cURL?

Comment: Yes I checked my generated tokens and keys using CURL , and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

my problem must have been with the twitter app I created on twitter. deleted and recreated the app and it worked fine. I am using play 2.4 . The only difference I can think of is that when creating the app on twitter first time I provided a made up url which didnt actually exist and it didnt work. Then I deleted that app and created a new one but provided my twitter account url as the web url and it worked.